# Laravel 10 Auth::routes() Location

Tags: authentication, routes, laravel-10

I have installed Laravel 10 and using the laravel bootstrap ui & auth. It's working fine for the default Authentication and Authorization, but I need to customize the routes and a minor process flow.

Now I not finding the actual route list location.

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the Auth::routes() List -- for Laravel 10**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController;

// Login and Logout Routes...
Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class,'login']);
Route::post('logout',  [LoginController::class,'logout'])->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showLinkRequestForm'])->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail'])->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showResetForm'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.update');

// Confirm Password 
Route::get('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'showConfirmForm'])->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'confirm']);

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', [VerificationController::class, 'show'])->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend',  [VerificationController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');
```

**And the Location is: **
*`vendor/laravel/ui/src/AuthRouteMethods.php`*

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm having the same problem